# Creating a Tableau script to save images

Tags: jpeg, heatmap, tableau-api

I need to create a map of the United States with some points indicating results on an academic research project.
I need to produce a map for every day of the project in order to send the maps to people who don't have Tableau. I intend to make a slideshow with the maps displaying the change in the map over the two months.
The problem is that this means creating about 60 maps.
My question is: Is there a way to automate this process and automatically produce a jpg file in the map tab of my Tableau worksheet for all days in the data set?

Comment: How many people is this work being sent to? If it's a handful, couldn't they install Tableau Reader instead?

Comment: These are meant for emailing to a very wide audience. We cannot ask them all to install the software.

Comment: Why not publish your workbooks to Tableau public and then email out a link?

Answer (score 1):

Can you make an animation? You can put your date element in the pages shelf and animate. From there you can create a screen capture of the animation and create a movie. If you want it to be an image, you could turn that movie into an animated gif or extract all the frames (search for ImageMagick for more on this).

Here's an example of an animated map.

http://apandre.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/motion-map-chart/